# Script to exctract data from CSV and generate http_build_query

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to pull data out of a CSV file and generate a http_build_query to submit as a http post

My data looks like this:

```
First,Last,Address,City,St,Zip,email,phone,dob,optindate,ipaddress,url
Abbey,Johnson,4004 S. Parker Dr. 206,Sioux Falls,SD,55106,abbey@email.com,6053451657,06/18/1924,4/19/2008 11:58:34,12.174.252.216,http://www.ecoupons.com/
```

My code looks like this:

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("test.2", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

$data = array('firstname' => "$line_of_text[0]",
            'lastname' => "$line_of_text[1]",
            'address' => "$line_of_text[2]",);

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

My result is:

```
firstname=Abbey&lastname=Johnson&address=4004+S.+Louise+Ave.+206
firstname=&lastname=&address=
```

I am not sure why the second line without the data is created and how do I keep the white spaces in the array data?

Thanks!

Comment: Why pull the data out of string/CSV format? Why not just send the whole thing as a post value? In addition, you cannot have two variables named the same thing. `firstname=Abbey&firstname=...` will overwrite each other. You need to use arrays like `firstname[]=Abbey&firstname[]=...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not need to send every column in the CSV but if I did how would I send the whole thing as a post value?

Comment: `$params = "?csv=" . rawurlencode(file_get_contents('test.2'));`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV does does seem to be valid or readable (can't see the new line ) so i use a simple of mine

Your address contains `,` which affects the way `fgetcsv` reads the file

Try

```
$fp= fopen("log.txt", "r");

while (!feof($fp) ) {
    list($firstname,$lastname,$address) = fgetcsv($fp);
    $data = array('firstname' => $firstname,
                'lastname' => $lastname,
                'address' => $address);
    echo http_build_query($data) . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Output

```
  firstname=Abbey&lastname=Johnso&address=4004+S.+Louise+Ave.+206
```